# What is the best utility function to Get Value from SqlDataReader in ado.net?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, ado.net

What is the best way to get value from a `SqlDataReader`?

I wrote a utility function to retrieve value by column name from underlying data type, anyone please suggest improvements to it.

The thing I consider inefficient is giving implementation for each type separately which will leave many types unhandled.

Can my code give compile type error for types which I did not handled? I considered using generic constraints but they are not help full in my case.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(SqlDataReader reader, string columnName,T defaultValue=default(T))
{
    int ordinal;

    // checking whether column name exist in reader result set
    try
    {
        ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException columnException)
    {
       var innerexception = new IndexOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Column name does not exist in specified SqlDataReader, {0}", columnException.Message), columnException);

       throw innerexception;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       throw e;
   }

   // Defining Types and their corresponding functions to be called.
   var typeDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<T>>
            {
                {typeof(Int16), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetInt16(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(Int32), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetInt32(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(Int64), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetInt64(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(String), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetString(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(Boolean), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetBoolean(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(Byte), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetByte(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(DateTime), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetDateTime(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(Char), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetChar(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(Decimal), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetDecimal(ordinal),typeof(T))},
                {typeof(Double), () => (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetDouble(ordinal),typeof(T))}
            };

   Type providedType = typeof (T);

   // Handling nullable types, If programmer wants to pass null value as default he should pass struct type with '?'.
   if (providedType.IsGenericType && 
       providedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>))
   {
       providedType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(providedType);
   }

   if (typeDictionary[providedType] == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentException("Not Supported Type");
   }

   var resultedValue = reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? defaultValue : typeDictionary[typeof (T)]();

   return resultedValue;
}
```

Comment: Why do you *need* a utility function? Why is the functionality/methods that the `SqlDataReader` class exposes not already sufficient?

Comment: Also, catch-and-release, whilst a popular form of fishing, isn't a sensible thing to do with exceptions. I'd advise removing that `catch (Exception e)` block.

Comment: @Daniel For getting values from reader against column I always have to check for null and cast it to relevant type which I want to minimize the code for.

Comment: Suggestions to improve working code belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/